# CSS cache update and CDNs

Tags: html, css, wordpress, caching

When I develop web applications, I'm used to add a ?ver=XXX at the end of my CSS URIs.

I'm updating a wordpress theme and I found a filter that removes any ?ver= from "static ressources" :

```
    add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'mb_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
    add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'mb_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

Searching the web I found that without removing thoses ver=, CDN may not work and do not cache the CSS files ! That's a big surprise to me as I used it everywhere.

I use this version to force browsers to update their cache when I modify the CSS (by versionning up). 
How do you force browser to understand the file must be downloaded again without using a ver= ?

```
-- 
Thank you 
Nicolas.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to your answers, here is the full answer :

In my theme there is this file "theme-functions.php" in the ~theme/lib directory.
This is the file that loads the css file using the enqueue_style function :

`wp_enqueue_style( '_mbbasetheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.min.css' );`

Using grunt as suggested, I was able to achieve the following steps :

- Compass the SASS file and make a unique css file ==> `style.css`
- Minify my unique css file to make it lighter ==> `style.min.css`
- Version my css file to make a unique file name ==> `style.4c72.min.css`

These steps use the following grunt-plugins :

- grunt-contrib-compass : with this grunt rule in Gruntfile.js

```
        compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                }
            }
        },
```

- grunt-contrib-cssmin : with this grunt rule in Gruntfile.js

```
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                keepSpecialComments: 1
            },
            minify: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '',
                src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
                dest: '',
                ext: '.min.css'
            }
        },
```

- grunt-wp-assets : with this grunt rule in Gruntfile.js

```
        version: {
            assets: {
                options: {
                    algorithm: 'sha1',
                    length: 4,
                    format: false,
                    rename: false,
                    minify: true,
                    manifest: 'manifest.json'
                },
                files: {
                    'lib/theme-functions.php': ['style.min.css']
                }
            }
        },
```

As you can see, the last one takes a file in argument to update the reference to the css file. After the grunt execution (actually a grunt-contrib-watch rule), the theme-functions.php is updated to :

`wp_enqueue_style( '_mbbasetheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.4c72.min.css' );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool such as Grunt (or gulp) to rev your assets:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-wp-assets 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev

Comment: Thank you scott, I'm checking grunt documentation. The aim of these tools is to change directly the file name so that there is no need to ad a rev= at the end. Is this the only way ?

Comment: I just installed the plugin and I wonder where to apply the php file update in wordpress. The name style.css is everywhere. Especially in file theme.php

Comment: @NicolasThery -- It will create a file such as style.01234567.css. This is one of the standard ways to bust a cache without using a query string. I am not sure how to implement in WP. You may want to post on the WP stack exchange.